# Rails select options tag - generating options from associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, html-select

I have a view that allows the user to add `list_items` to one of their `shopping_lists`. I want the options for select to be the names of their lists, but I need those names mapped to respective `list_id` in order to have the correct associations. Here's my current `select tag`:

```
<tr>
  <% item.inventory_items.each do |product| %>
    <td>
      <%= form_tag("/list_items", method: "post") do %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag(:item_id, item.id) %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag(:inventory_item_id, product.id) %> 
      <%= select_tag(:shopping_list_id, options_for_select(current_user.shopping_lists)) %>
      <%= submit_tag("$#{product.price}", class: "btn btn-primary") %>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

How can I display the names of a user's `shopping_lists` as the options, but return the relative `shopping_list_id` as the value for that option?

ShoppingList `belongs_to :user`
User `has_many :shopping_lists`

Currently my select tag renders a dropdown selection of a user's shopping lists, but the options are listed in the form, '#. Clicking the submit button doesn't actually add the the item to the list either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in Rails Api documentation:

```
options_for_select([["Dollar", "$"], ["Kroner", "DKK"]])
# => <option value="$">Dollar</option>
# => <option value="DKK">Kroner</option>
```

`options_for_select` receives an Array of Arrays. Inner Arrays are only two elements: `["name", "value"]`.

You can create a class method in your ShoppingList model as follows:

```
def self.options_for_list(shopping_lists)
  shopping_lists.map do |sl|
    [ sl.name, sl.id ]
  end
end
```

It returns the Array you need, then:

```
<%= select_tag :shopping_list_id, options_for_select(ShoppingList.options_for_list(current_user.shopping_lists)) %>
```

**EDIT**:

Or use a helper method:

```
def shopping_list_select_tag(shopping_lists, options = {})
  select_options = shopping_lists.map do |sl|
                     [ sl.name, sl.id ]
                   end
  select_tag :shopping_list_id, options_for_select(select_options), options
end
```

Then,

```
<%= shopping_list_select_tag current_user.shopping_lists %>
```

Comment: I was thinking for a better solution: a helper method. See my edit.